# emcee - why values outside of prior space

Tags: python, montecarlo, emcee

I am specifying my priors to be none negative in the following way:

```
def lnprior(theta):
    sig,mu  = theta
    if 0.01 < sig < 2.0 and 0.01 < mu < 1.0:
        return(0.0)
    return(-np.inf)
```

I then follow the cookbook on the  [emcee](https://github.com/dfm/emcee) web page:

```
def lnprob(theta,lightcurve,noisecurve):
    lp = lnprior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return(-np.inf)
    return(lp + lnlike(theta,lightcurve,noisecurve)) # lightcurve and noisecurve are np.arrays
```

I do not alter (at least not knowingly) `mu` in `lnlike` in any way....

When I then generate a corner plot using `fig = corner.corner(samples, labels=["$\sigma$", "$\mu$",'$c$'],color=sns.xkcd_rgb["amber"])`, where corner is [corner](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py/blob/master/docs/index.rst), I still get a couple of points that fall in the lower two quadrants. Why is this ?

---

Here is how I defined lnlike:

```
def lnlike(theta,lightcurve,noisecurve):
    sig = theta[0]
    mu = theta[1]
    lightcurve = adder(lightcurve,mu) #simply adding lightcurve + mu 
    x = binMaker(mu,lightcurve,noisecurve) # computing x values as a function of mu
    y, yerr = detectionFrequency(lightcurve,noisecurve,mu) # a function which computes a real valued number based on f(x,mu,lightcurve,noisecurve)
    return(np.sum((y-PDF(x,sig,np.log(mu)))**2/yerr))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have initialized some of the walkers outside of the region defined by your prior. In this case it can take quite a while for them to get "sucked back" into the feasible region.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, even with walkers initialized inside the prior regions. One (blunt) solution is to simply add the if statements from lnprior to your lnlike function.

Comment: Are you still on the EMCEE topic? I have a question, please

Answer (score 0):

To get best-fit values of each parameter within their prior range, just put prior range in bracks () i.e.

```
def lnprior(theta):
sig,mu  = theta
if (0.01 < sig < 2.0 and 0.01 < mu < 1.0):
    return(0.0)
return(-np.inf)
```

Hope this will work for you. Please let me know further.